# can't upgrade or downgrade spyder 3.2.8 niether using anaconda navigator nor conda propmt?

Tags: spyder

I'm using spyder 3.2.8 with anaconda navigator 5.2.
I had a problem seeing variables in spyder 3.2.8 so I wanted to downgrade it to version 3.2.0 using anaconda navigator, upgrading process completed but the version is still 3.2.8 . Then I tried to upgrade it to 3.3, but same problem. even tried "pip install --upgrade spyder" but no luck!

Comment: I even can't upgrade jupyter in anaconda!

Answer (score 0):

you should not use pip with anaconda or spyder. Use conda instead. So try: `conda upgrade spyder` If that doesn't work please leave a comment about what happened and any messages printed to screen. Pip has been known to break the anaconda distribution.  You can also try conda install anaconda

Comment: I ran the code on conda prompt, firstly without admin permission and faced this error: `Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'anaconda::conda-4.5.9-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')`

Comment: And then ran it again with admin permission. this time everything were OK. I restarted the laptop and opened spyder, but it's still on 3.2.8! what I saw was like this(I have to put it in 2 comments):

Comment: `Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py']`

Comment: `DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py', '--reset']
/ DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'`

Comment: `DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py', '--reset']
done`